# program cannot be opened

Tags: android, eclipse

below are my codes for an android application . to create a database to store name and email . 
however when i am running the program in the simulator for android it does not works and says that my application has stopped. 
there is not any error appearing in my codes that prevent me from running it 
please help .

```
String fname , lname, email;
SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("MYDB1",MODE_PRIVATE , null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT TEXISTS Student(fname VARCHAR , lname VARCHAR , email VARCHAR);");
}
private void Adddata(View view)
{

    EditText edittext1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    EditText edittext2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    EditText edittext3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

    fname=edittext1.getText().toString();
    lname=edittext2.getText().toString();
    email=edittext3.getText().toString();

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Student Values('"+fname+"', '"+lname+"','"+email+"');");
}

private void Showdata(View view)
{
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from Student", null);

    int count =c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();
    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
    tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    TableRow tableRow;
    TextView textView,textView1,textView2,textView3,textView4,textView5;

    tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());


    textView.setText("FirstName");
    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    textView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    tableRow.addView(textView);

    textView4=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView4.setText("LastName");
    textView4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    textView4.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    textView4.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    tableRow.addView(textView4);

    textView5=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView5.setText("Email");
    textView5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    textView5.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    textView5.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    tableRow.addView(textView5);

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

    for (Integer j = 0; j< count; j++)

    {
     tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
     textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fname")));

         textView2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lname")));

             textView3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                textView3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("email")));

                textView1.setPadding(20, 20, 20,20);
                textView2.setPadding(20, 20, 20,20);
                textView3.setPadding(20, 20, 20,20);

                tableRow.addView(textView1);

                tableRow.addView(textView2);

                tableRow.addView(textView3);

                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
                c.moveToNext();
                        }

    setContentView(tableLayout);
    db.close();
        }

public void close(View view)
{
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

this is my logcat

```
04-15 05:33:35.650: D/dalvikvm(929): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-15 05:33:37.460: E/SQLiteLog(929): (1) near "TEXISTS": syntax error
04-15 05:33:37.460: D/AndroidRuntime(929): Shutting down VM
04-15 05:33:37.460: W/dalvikvm(929): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4aebba8)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929): Process: com.example.studentdatabase, PID: 929
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.studentdatabase/com.example.studentdatabase.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TEXISTS": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT TEXISTS Student(fname VARCHAR , lname VARCHAR , email VARCHAR);
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TEXISTS": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT TEXISTS Student(fname VARCHAR , lname VARCHAR , email VARCHAR);
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at com.example.studentdatabase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-15 05:33:37.470: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: I only see commented out code

Comment: i could not post the codes without commenting it off..

Comment: What is the logcat output?

Comment: done this is my output for error

Answer (score 0):

Its a Typo. TEXTISTS => EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

Read your stacktrace :

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TEXISTS": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT TEXISTS Student(fname VARCHAR , lname VARCHAR , email VARCHAR);

Change `TEXISTS` to `EXISTS`, and it should work better.